# If Kolmogorov continuity criterion gives the optimal Hölder regularity then does the process have all moments?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Although very useful in the Gaussian (or other infinite moment) setting, Kolmogorov continuity criterion is non optimal in the finite moment setting. For example, let $X(t)=Zt$ where $Z$ is a random variable with $m$ moments. Then we have that
$$E[|X(t)-X(s)|^p]=E[|Z|^p]|t-s|^p,$$
so Kolmogorov continuity criterion gives that $X$ is $\alpha$ Hölder for any $\alpha<(p-1)/p=1-1/p$. Although $X$ is Lipschitz, Kolmogorov continuity criterion only gives you this in the limit as $p\to\infty$ (and even then, you don't get exactly $1$ you just get $1^-$).

However if $X$ is a stochastic process with infinitely many moments of Hölder regularity $\gamma$ then Kolmogorov continuity criterion can pick this out. Formally, suppose that $|X(t)-X(s)|\leq Z |t-s|^\gamma$ where $Z$ is a random variable with infinitely many moments. Then $$E[|X(t)-X(s)|^p]\leq E[|Z|^p]|t-s|^{p\gamma},$$
so $X$ is $\alpha$ Hölder for any $\alpha<(p\gamma-1)/p$ which as $p\to\infty$ gives any $\alpha<\gamma$.

I am curious about the converse.

> Let $X$ be a continuous real valued stochastic process of optimal Hölder regularity $\gamma^\ast$ in the sense that $X$ is $\gamma$ Hölder for $\gamma<\gamma^\ast$ and it is nowhere $\gamma$ Hölder for $\gamma>\gamma^\ast$. Furthermore, suppose that for any $\gamma<\gamma^\ast$ there is a constant $C>0$ and a pair $(p,q)$ with $(q-1)/p>\gamma$ so that $$E[|X(t)-X(s)|^p]\leq C|t-s|^q.$$
> Then for all $\gamma<\gamma^\ast$ does there exist a random variable $Z$ with infinitely many moments so that $|X(t)-X(s)|\leq Z |t-s|^\gamma$?

In short:

> Suppose that $X$ has Hölder regularity $\gamma^\ast$ (but nowhere better) AND Kolmogorov continuity criterion gives a Hölder regularity of $\gamma^{\ast}$ then does $X$ have infinitely many moments?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @user479223 I fixed the short version of the question to match the actual question, since it confused both Ofer and myself. The "nowehere better" is the whole point why the question isn't trivial.

Comment: @MartinHairer Thanks for the edit. I use "the Holder regularity" to mean the optimal Holder exponent (perhaps not achieved as is the case with BM) of a function/process but I understand that conventions differ.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the answer is "no", here is almost a proof. Take $\tau_n$ to be an i.i.d. sequence of uniform $[0,1]$ random variables and take $Z_n$ an i.i.d. sequence of random variables having second moments but no better. Say $\mathbb{P}(Z_n > K) \sim K^{-2} (\log K)^{-2}$. Consider then the process on $[0,1]$ given by
$$
X(t) = \sum_{n \ge 2} \frac{Z_n}{n(\log n)^2} |t-\tau_n|^\alpha.
$$
It is not difficult to see that, when $\alpha < 1/2$,
$$
\mathbb{E} \big||t-\tau_n|^\alpha-|s-\tau_n|^\alpha\big|^2 \le C |t-s|^{1+2\alpha}
$$
for some constant $C$, so that $X$ satisfies Kolmogorov's criterion with $\gamma^* = \alpha$ and $p=2$. Obviously $X$ fails to be better than $\alpha$-Hölder at the (random) dense set of points $\{\tau_n\}$ and it also fails to have moments higher than the second one.

It is not clear however whether it fails to be $(\alpha +\delta)$-Hölder for arbitrary $\delta > 0$ at *every* point in $[0,1]$.